# Scroll table view row to top when keyboard appears BUG

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with `UITextViews` in each cell. I want to move the cell in which the user is editing the `UITextView` to the top of the table view.

This is easily achieved by:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height - textViewHeight, 0);
```

However I have a very weird issue, which I can not find anything on, when searching for it. The cell is not moved up, until the keyboard has not finished animating on to the screen, no matter which method I set the `contentInset` in. It's as if the keyboard animation has some kind of priority.

After investigating, I found that setting the `contentOffset` at the same time, will actually move the cell up, even before the keyboard has finished animating.

Can somebody explain this behaviour to me, or explain whats going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you `UITextfield` or `UITextview` will began editing method call at that time you can use UITableView Method

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height - textViewHeight, 0);
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)
```

and you can scroll to top. i hope this will help you

Comment: As I wrote, it does not work, no matter in which delegate method I call it. It still waits for the keyboard to appear.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way for these kind of scenerio's just install IQKeyboardManager Pods and it will automatically scroll tableview when you click on UITextView ,You don't need to write anything else.

Comment: But, I want to understand what is going on... Not install a third-party library

Answer (score 0):

you are using `UITableView` with `ViewController`. But to achieve what you want the best way is to use a `UITableViewController`.because,
**It autoamtically scroll up (scroll above to keyboard and focus on the editing textfield) when user enter any data.**

Comment: I need the functionality of a UIViewController, such as having a main UIView

Comment: which functionalities you want ... take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

try observing keyboard notifications UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, put your code into the selector method.